# angular onclick method to calculate a function on a new page

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

im working on an bmi app with ionic angular (newest version). The goal is to have a button which takes the input from the input fields, which goes on to start a method which checks for not allowed inputs (this is already done). After that it needs to start the results page in which the input got inserted into the function and printed out. I dont know how i could to it.

I got the button with a method which checks for false inputs and if everything is alright it starts the result-page. Html input page:

```
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Gewicht</ion-label>
    <ion-input clearInput type="number" placeholder="kg" [(ngModel)]="eingabeKG" min="1" onkeypress="return (event.charCode !=8 && event.charCode ==1 || (event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57))"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Körpergröße</ion-label>
    <ion-input clearInput type="number" placeholder="cm" [(ngModel)]="eingabeCM" min="1" onkeypress="return (event.charCode !=8 && event.charCode ==1 || (event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57))"></ion-input>
  
</ion-item>
  <ion-button expand="block" (click)="onBerechnenButton()">Umrechnen</ion-button>
</ion-content>
```

and typescript:

```
export class HomePage {

public eingabeKG = null;
public eingabeCM = null;

  constructor( private alertCtrl: AlertController,
    private navCtrl  : NavController) {
    
    }
async onBerechnenButton() {
f (this.eingabeKG == null && this.eingabeCM == null) {

  this.zeigeFehlerDialog("Bitte Gewicht und Körpergröße eingeben!");
  return;
  } else
  this.navCtrl.navigateForward(['/ausgabe']);

let navigationTarget = `/ausgabe?eingabeKG=${this.eingabeKG}&eingabeCM=${this.eingabeCM}`;
  this.navCtrl.navigateForward(navigationTarget);

async zeigeFehlerDialog(nachricht: string) {

  const meinAlert =
        await this.alertCtrl.create({ header  : "Fehler",
                                      message : nachricht,
                                      buttons : [ "Ok" ]
                                    });
  await meinAlert.present();
}
}
```

typescript o resultpage:

```
export class AusgabePage {

public eingabeKG: string;
public eingabeCM: string;

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { 

  this.eingabeKG = activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParamMap.get( "eingabeKG" )!;
  this.eingabeCM = activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParamMap.get( "eingabeCM" )!;
  }
  

}
```

in the result page html im just showing the 2 input numbers.

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-text>
<p>
  {{eingabeKG}} {{eingabeCM}}
</p>
    
  </ion-text>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
async onBerechnenButton() {
  if (this.eingabeKG == null && this.eingabeCM == null) {
    this.zeigeFehlerDialog("Bitte Gewicht und Körpergröße eingeben!");
    return;
  }
  this.navCtrl.navigateForward(['/ausgabe'], {
    queryParams: {
      eingabeKG: this.eingabeKG,
      eingabeCM: this.eingabeCM,
    }
  });
}
```

~

```
export class AusgabePage implements OnInit {
  eingabeKG?: string;
  eingabeCM?: string;

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.eingabeKG = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParamMap.get("eingabeKG");
    this.eingabeCM = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParamMap.get("eingabeCM");
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer :) but how am i suppose to get the inputs into a function which calculates the 2 inputs and spits it to the html page?

Comment: Once you have the two inputs in AusgabePage, you can juste perform the calculation at the end of the ngOnInit and store the result as a property. Then display it on your page. Or your can make it directly on the template, e.g. {{ (eingabeKG + eingabeCM) / 2 }}